# How to make a process running for ever after ending Android main process

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app and I want to create a process that runs in background AFTER ending the main process. It is like whatsUp running after closing the main application. This collect incoming messages and show it with the icon.  I have tried to start a service by ending the main process. It runs for a while and then ends.. How to to do this?

Comment: Use Android Service. Show Example of Android  Alarm Service.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: the service is the best option for it, check the android services [Click link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot I did use service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using services . All you need to do is to create a class extends it with service class override method on startCommand and return Service.StartSticky. The startsticky means that your service continuosly run  even when you restart your phone. If you do not return sticky then it will automatically kill if you restarts your mobile . And also register a broadcast reciever so that your service will send data to your activity if your service gets new data from the server then it will aend it to the broadcast and in broadcast will notify the user for new data